# Qt torrent example stuck at searching

Tags: qt, bittorrent

i have a problem.

I am working on download-only bittorrent client. Everything was going well,

but i had a pause about 2 weeks, while i changed nothing. Now i my program is stuck at searching. I also tried the qt torrent example. Same problem there on both PCs. Linux/Windows 7/Windows 8 (all 64-bit). Do u know what can cause this problem? Also tried to turn on/off firewall. No change.

I have it as a school project, im pretty scared about making totally new code, if i have about  2 weeks to finish it.

Here is the link of qt-example
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-torrent.html

Thanks for help
Martin

Comment: You need to show us some code.

Comment: Well, i think the torrent example would be enough. Basically it is the same app, and this app doesnt work too :( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-torrent.html